# Evaluating a boolean variable in PHP: Should one use If/Else or Switch?

Tags: php, boolean, switch-statement, if-statement

I love getting myself into these ridiculous situations where I over-evaluate my coding practices, so here goes!

This question probably transcends PHP (as well as sanity).  When evaluating a Boolean variable, which of these is best practice?  (assume that there's too much `//do stuff` for a ternary)

```
if ($bool) {
    // do true stuff
} else {
    // do false stuff
}
```

or

```
switch ($bool) {
    case true:
        // do true stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do false stuff
        break;
}
```

I'm interested more in performance and/or idiosyncratic considerations than blanket statements like "If/Else looks better," "Always use Switch," or "Do what you feel is right."

That is, unless there really isn't a difference.

Comment: Why are people so anal about performance of these things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `if-else` version. It's very clear and easy to understand.

You shouldn't really use `switch` unless you have multiple (> 2) values to switch on. You gain nothing using switch in this case (other than making your code less comprehensible).

If there was any difference in performance, the `if-else` version would be faster, although if was there any difference it would really be negligible.

This would be a micro-optimization if anything. Don't do it. Before you introduce any "optimizations" to your code, profile it and identify your bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks.  For what it's worth I'm not profiling my code afterward and thinking "Man I wonder what would be faster."  It was more of a "What should I tend to do when writing the conditional in the first place."

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you should also check that your variable is really a boolean (and not "", 0, or null which may also evaluate to false)

```
if($bool === false) {
 // false stuff
} else if($bool === true) {
 // true stuff
} else {
 /// WTF???
}
```

Comment: `else { throw FileNotFoundException }`